# Padrino Admi - Omniauth - Can't Access Restricted Space after Successful Login

Tags: ruby, omniauth, padrino

I primarily come from a PHP and ASP.NET background. Recently I got involved with Ruby and am starting an interesting relationship with `Padrino`. Not too much like Rails and not too less like Sinatra.

I am making first serious application using `Padrino` and it didn't take long to get stuck and would appreciate your help.

The issue with what I believe is with `Padrino Admin`. I am trying make users login to my website using `Facebook` and [Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth).

I have been following this tutorial: [Padrino and Omniauth Overview](http://www.padrinorb.com/blog/padrino-and-omniauth-overview).

The application is hosted at `Heroku`.

**Result**: On `Facebook` login, an account is crated ( in the database ). But when I reach the restricted area, I get redirected back to the login page.

Here is what I have.

**app.rb**

```
module PDeen
  class App < Padrino::Application

    register Padrino::Admin::AccessControl

    register SassInitializer
    register Padrino::Rendering
    register Padrino::Mailer
    register Padrino::Helpers

    enable :sessions

    # get '/' do 
    #   "Welcome to me @ internet"
    # end

    use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :facebook,  'xxxx', 'yyyy' 
      # provider :facebook, 'app_id', 'app_secret'
    end

    set :login_page, "/login" # determines the url login occurs

    access_control.roles_for :any do |role|
      role.protect "/profile"
      role.protect "/admin" # here a demo path
    end

    # now we add a role for users
    access_control.roles_for :users do |role|
      role.allow "/profile"
    end

    get :index do 
      'Hi'
    end

    get :login do
      slim :'index'
    end

    get :profile do
      content_type :text
      current_account.to_yaml
    end

    get :destroy do
      set_current_account(nil)
      redirect url(:index)
    end

    get :auth, :map => '/auth/:provider/callback' do
      auth    = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      # account = Account.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || 
      #           Account.create_with_omniauth(auth)
      # 
      account = User.first( :provider => auth["provider"], :uid => auth["uid"] )

      if ! account.nil?
        set_current_account(account)  
        redirect :existing
      end

      if account.nil? 
        # Create account
        account           = User.new 
        account.uid       = auth['uid']
        account.name      = auth['name']
        account.provider  = auth['provider']
        account.email     = auth['user_info']['email'] if auth['user_info']
        account.role      = 'users'

        account.save
      end 

      set_current_account(account)
      #redirect "http://" + request.env["HTTP_HOST"] + url(:profile)
      redirect :new
    end

    get :existing do 
      'existing'
    end

    get '/session/test' do 
      session[:test] = 'This is a test'
    end

    get '/session/print' do 
      "You saved: #{session[:test]}"
    end
  end
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  # property <name>, <type>
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :email, String
  property :role, String
  property :uid, String
  property :provider, String

end
```

What happens >>

1. List item
2. I go to `[server]/profile` ~> redirects to `[server]/login`
3. I click on Facebook ~> takes to the page to accept the app ~> redirects back to the app
4. I go to `[server]/profile` ~> redirects to `[server]/login`

I thought that sessions are not working. In the time I was working on my first PHP app, I had similar session based issue. But it turned out to be that it wroks. That is where the `[server]/session/test` and `[server]/session/print` came in.

When I login to the `Padriono console` in `Heroku` and use `User.all` I see the entry.

I also see that the user gets authenticated. Some thing has to be with `

I checked the `Padrino admin` `Accounts` modal. I think the important parameters would be `id` and `role`.

Have I done some thing wrong?

Thanks in advance. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like accordin to [this](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/master/padrino-admin/lib/padrino-admin/access_control.rb) The padrino authentication accepts a modal named `Accont`.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the Padrino source code, I noticed that it is expecting the `Account` class for `Padrino Admin` authentication.

I was assuming, I could make any class and just use it. But for the moment, I have modified the `Account.rb` modal and instead of using `User` ( above ) I used `Account`.

I write this just as I got it resolved, so the validation section of the modal is commented out.

```
class Account
  include DataMapper::Resource
  include DataMapper::Validate
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  # Properties
  property :id,               Serial
  property :name,             String
  property :surname,          String
  property :email,            String
  property :crypted_password, String, :length => 70
  property :role,             String

  property :uid,              String
  property :display_name,     String
  property :provider,         String

  # # Validations
  # validates_presence_of      :email, :role
  # validates_presence_of      :password,                          :if => :password_required
  # validates_presence_of      :password_confirmation,             :if => :password_required
  # validates_length_of        :password, :min => 4, :max => 40,   :if => :password_required
  # validates_confirmation_of  :password,                          :if => :password_required
  # validates_length_of        :email,    :min => 3, :max => 100
  # validates_uniqueness_of    :email,    :case_sensitive => false
  # validates_format_of        :email,    :with => :email_address
  # validates_format_of        :role,     :with => /[A-Za-z]/

  # Callbacks
  before :save, :encrypt_password

  ##
  # This method is for authentication purpose
  #
  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    account = first(:conditions => ["lower(email) = lower(?)", email]) if email.present?
    account && account.has_password?(password) ? account : nil
  end

  ##
  # This method is used by AuthenticationHelper
  #
  def self.find_by_id(id)
    get(id) rescue nil
  end

  def has_password?(password)
    ::BCrypt::Password.new(crypted_password) == password
  end

  private
  def password_required
    crypted_password.blank? || password.present?
  end

  def encrypt_password
    self.crypted_password = ::BCrypt::Password.create(password) if password.present?
  end
end
```

Note that just after the role, I added 3 more fields namely `uid`, `display_name` and `provider`.

It seems as though, `uid` `provder` and `role` are what is important for the access control.

The `controller` / `route` are the same except for one minor change. That is the Model name.

```
  if account.nil? 
    # Create account
    account               = Account.new
```

Would be interesting to use own modal with `Omniauth` and `Padrino Admin helpers`. But for the moment, this is great!